# Where do people use the "Here document" on UNIX systems?

Tags: here-document

Where do people use the "Here document" on UNIX systems?

Where is it used in reality?

Comment: People use it in a number of ways. What's your question, really? I'm voting to close as too broad.

Answer (score 4):

ftp and the like are good examples.

For instance, if you want to stablish an ftp connection and retrieve some files you can create a script that does something like:

```
#!/bin/bash
lftp machine -uUser,Passwd << END
    cd your_dir
    get your_file
    bye
END
```

You have automated files retrieval with a "Here document"

Answer (score 3):

It is often used for multi line output.

Compare

```
echo "first line" >output
echo "second line" >>output
echo "third line" >>output
```

and

```
cat >output <<"END"
first line
second line
third line
END
```

Both should do exactly the same, but especially with long text the second version is easier.

Answer (score 0):

A here document is a special-purpose code block. It uses a form of I/O redirection to feed a command list to an interactive program or a command, such as ftp, cat, or the ex text editor.

A more detailed example and explanation can be found here:

[Here Documents](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/here-docs.html)

A `grep` command example for "Here document":

```
grep this <<"END"
> this is an example
> with example
> END
this is an example
```

Comment: And this is reality for whom?

Comment: Just another "Here document" example using `grep` command.

Comment: But the OP is not asking for that, the question is "where is this used in reality".

Comment: Added references for explanation.