# how to exit in bash script from ProFTPD via netcat after some copy operations

Tags: bash, netcat, exit, proftpd

I am connecting to a proftpd server via netcat

```
nc 10.10.239.150 21
```

Then I am doing some copy operations like
"The mod_copy module implements SITE CPFR and SITE CPTO commands"

[image]

After "250 Copy successful" i want to exit this netcat connection and continue with the bash script.

I already tried following call, with CPFR and CPTO instructions outsourced to a msg.txt file

```
nc 10.10.115.253 21 < msg.txt
```

But still I dont know how to exit the netcat proftpd connection after successful proftpd operations.

Several tried EOF instructions are not understood by nc/proftpd:
Only the CTRL C user input does the job, but this should be done automatically.

[image]

Comment: Does typing Control-D terminate it? If not, OS and version of netcat are you using?

Comment: alternately, you could use lftp which supports site commands.

Comment: Read `man expect`. `expect` can automate some or all interactions with a program.

Comment: @GordonDavisson CTRL C terminates , yes. But I want to run the whole script without user input.

Comment: @A.B should be designed specifically for proftpd

Comment: @florian.isopp Control-D (end of file), not Control-C (abort). But if you're trying to run it from a script, using an input file (like `< msg.txt`) or [here-document](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/232460/where-do-people-use-the-here-document-on-unix-systems/232466#232466) should work. Do they?

Comment: @GordonDavisson I m already using an input file, but EOF or similar is not understood then from proftpd to exit the proftpd sess

Comment: @florian.isopp proftpd is irrelevant; I expect `nc` to close its TCP connection when it reaches EOF of its input. If it's not, what version of `nc` are you using, and on what OS?

Comment: it latest kali linux. nc -h is v1.10-46 . "EOF is not understood" (see updated screenshot in the question)

Comment: nc is less specific to any FTP server than lftp is. In short lftp is more specific to ProFTPD than you'll ever achieve with nc.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have either a kali linux system or a ProFTPD server available to test with, so this is somewhat speculative, but I see a couple of things that might work.

First, a bit of explanation: it's really up to the client to terminate the connection to the server, not by sending a command, but by closing the TCP connection (technically, by sending a TCP/IP packet with the "fin" (finish) flag). So what's really needed here is to find a way to tell the `nc` program to close the connection after all operations are finished. And how you do that depends on the `nc` program (they're not all the same).

Possibility 1: some versions of `nc` need a `-N` option to tell them to close the TCP session after hitting EOF on their input. Check your man page to see if the version you have needs this.

Possibility 2: some versions have a `-w` option that lets you specify an "idle timeout" (in seconds) for the connection. Basically, if you specify `nc -w 5 ...` it'll close the connection after 5 seconds of inactivity. Again, check your man page.